# Blocked using simpleform wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Working with 2 models: Films and Categories, and trying to setup a form for Films that uses an association with Categories to prepopulate what it can be found in the dropdown. If I delete `, :collection => Category.all(order: 'prototype'), prompt: "Choose a category"` from the films/_form, I see that the 'prototype' field of the categories is not correctly rendered and instead I see something like:

[image]

Checked out the [simpleform docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations) but don't find anything that can help. *Edited to include a better link where can be seen what I have used as suggested in simpleform.

film.rb

```
  class Film < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :categories

  end
```

category.rb

```
  class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :film

  end
```

films/_form.htm.erb

```
  <%= simple_form_for @film do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title, required: false %>
    <%= f.association :categories, :collection => Category.all(order: 'prototype'), prompt: "Choose a category" %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>
```

categories/_form.htm.erb

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@category) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :prototype %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

trace in the terminal

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0):
  app/views/films/_form.html.erb:3:in `block in _app_views_films__form_html_erb___839547296437048808_70229269835880'
  actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in`block in capture'
  actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'

Answer (score 1):

The simple form docs didn't help you because your problem isn't with simple form but with how you're using Active Record. As of rails 4, you no longer pass options to `all`:

```
Company.all(order: 'prototype')
```

should be

```
Company.order('prototype')
```

Comment: Corrected that, but in the simpleform docs states it the other way. The wrong_number of arguments it's not anymore displayed but the #<Category:0x007... issue persists, and no value is passed when creating a new record of Film.